# Why is my neural net only predicting one class (binary classification)?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network

I am having some trouble with my ANN. It is only predicting '0.' The dataset is imbalanced (10:1), ALTHOUGH, I undersampled the training dataset, so I am unsure of what is going on. I am getting 92-93% accuracy on the balanced training set, although on testing (on an unbalanced test set) it just predicts zeroes. Unsure of where to go from here. Anything helps. The data has been one hot encoded and scaled.

```
#create 80/20 train-test split
train, test = train_test_split(selection, test_size=0.2)

# Class count
count_class_0, count_class_1 = train.AUDITED_FLAG.value_counts()

# Divide by class
df_class_0 = train[train['AUDITED_FLAG'] == 0]
df_class_1 = train[train['AUDITED_FLAG'] == 1]

df_class_0_under = df_class_0.sample(count_class_1)
train_under = pd.concat([df_class_0_under, df_class_1], axis=0)

print('Random under-sampling:')
print(train_under.AUDITED_FLAG.value_counts())

train_under.AUDITED_FLAG.value_counts().plot(kind='bar', title='Count (target)');

Random under-sampling:
1.0    112384
0.0    112384

#split features and labels 
y_train = np.array(train_under['AUDITED_FLAG'])
X_train = train_under.drop('AUDITED_FLAG', axis=1)
y_test = np.array(test['AUDITED_FLAG'])
X_test = test.drop('AUDITED_FLAG', axis=1)
y_train = y_train.astype(int)
y_test = y_test.astype(int)


# define model
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(6, input_dim=179, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(30, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

# fit model
history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=5, batch_size=16, verbose=1)

#validate
test_loss, test_acc = model.evaluate(X_test, y_test)

# evaluate the model
_, train_acc = model.evaluate(X_train, y_train, verbose=0)
_, test_acc = model.evaluate(X_test, y_test, verbose=0)

print('Train: %.3f, Test: %.3f' % (train_acc, test_acc))
print('test_acc:', test_acc)

# plot history
pyplot.plot(history.history['acc'], label='train')
#pyplot.plot(history.history['val_acc'], label='test')
```

Train: 0.931, Test: 0.921

```
#preds
y_pred = model.predict(X_test)
y_pred_bool = np.argmax(y_pred, axis=1)

# #plot confusion matrix 
y_actu = pd.Series(y_test, name='Actual')
y_pred_bool = pd.Series(y_pred_bool, name='Predicted')

print(pd.crosstab(y_actu, y_pred_bool))
```

'''

```
Predicted       0
Actual           
0           300011
1            28030
```

Comment: Is the test data also under sampled ? If not the model can easily achieve .90 accuracy by always predicting 0, correct ? Your choice of model is a bit strange... you do from 179 dimensions to 6 and then expand. Try a decreasing pattern e.g. 80 -> 30 -> 1. 5 epochs may be a bit little. Use the validation_data option to fit and plot both accuracy and loss. You want to avoid overfitting the training data.

Comment: the test data is not undersampled. The answer below was the issue, i was just evaluating the model wrong. The model itself was just a placeholder, i wont be using 6 -> 30 haha. Thank you though! hope I can tweak this thing to perform well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not right:

```
y_pred_bool = np.argmax(y_pred, axis=1)
```

Argmax is only used with categorical cross-entropy loss and softmax outputs. For binary cross-entropy and sigmoid outputs, you should round the outputs, which is equivalent to thresholding predictions > 0.5:

```
y_pred_bool = np.round(y_pred)
```

This is what Keras does to compute binary accuracy.

Comment: Thank you! Don't know how I missed that!